# How to avoid logging request in Locust without using context manager?

Tags: python, locust

The [Locust documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#validating-responses) explains that a request can be prevented from being logged by using a context manager and raising an exception. For example:

```
try:
    with self.client.get('/wont_be_logged', catch_response=True) as response:
        raise RuntimeError
catch RuntimeError
    pass
```

Is there a way to achieve the same without having to use a context manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not detract from cyberwiz's answer as ultimately you could just do your own requests and get the same behavior, but if you really want to just use Locust's client and not manage another client yourself, you can. `catch_response=True` should be enough for it to not automatically fire `success` or `failure` Events. You can then manually fire events with whatever you want after that.

Demo Locust file:

```
from locust import HttpUser
from locust.user.task import task


class TestUser(HttpUser):

    host = "http://localhost:8089"

    @task
    def test_call(self):
        r = self.client.get("/", catch_response=True)
        print("Test")
        print(r.elapsed)
        self.environment.events.request_success.fire(
            request_type="POST",
            name="/somewhere_new",
            response_time=r.elapsed.microseconds / 1000,
            response_length=13,
        )
```

Again, doing it this way doesn't save much it works.

Comment: So just using `catch_response=True` makes the request not to be logged; no need to use a with statement as I originally thought.

Comment: Huh. I didnt think about that. I’d consider this behaviour a bug though (i’ve even tried to make using catch_response=True without a with block throw an exception to help people avoid accidentally doing this and landing in this unexpected situation, but havent yet found a way)

Answer (score 1):

Just do the request yourself (without using `self.client`)

For example by using `requests.get(...)`

(note that this will use a different session so it wont use the same cookies or underlying http connection)